# cshtml is not able to format correctly in VS2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017

for the IDE VS2017, usually the code can be formatted by using CTRL + K + CTRL + D.

However, when the file is an cshtml and it contains the backend symbol @

The operation will fail. No code is changed or code is changed unexpectedly.

Is there any way to format cshtml file properly?

Thanks.

Comment: Bad formatting of (complex) razor pages seems to be a known issue for Microsoft : https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/169910/razor-cshtml-bad-automatic-formatting.html Did you try to just format selections with Ctrl+K, Ctrl+F ? Poor man's solution, I know, but if formatting the whole document is broken..

Comment: it doesn't work, all in all i really need a solution which can format an entire .cshtml like when I doing that on my .cs. :(